# Remove gestures from RatingBar

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, gesture

I have an Activity with several RatingBars on it so my users can rate many different things.  My problem is that this makes it difficult for my users to scroll up and down the screen.

If you attempt to slide your finger vertically on the screen and the first spot you touch is over a RatingBar, the RatingBar tries to capture the gesture itself instead of passing it along once your finger moves off of it (with a RatingBar, you can swipe horizontally to move the rating up and down).

I've even tried turning focus off, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Somebody has to have had this problem before.  Has no one tried putting a RatingBar in a ListView or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the rating bar to isIndicator(true)

```
ratingBar.isIndicator(true);
```

I guess you would need to use those rating bars at some point in the application, you can set your edittexts or whatever to set the rating bars to normal again so you can rate. Once the rating is done, with a OnRatingBarChangeListener set the rating bars back to indicators

Better late than never!